# Unit Testing in Nancy causing Routebuilder exception using TinyIoc

Tags: unit-testing, nancy, tinyioc

Getting a System.MissingMethodException, Method not found: 'Void RouteBuilder.set_Item()

```
Get["/foo"] = parameters => { return Bar(Request);};
```

This runs fine when calling from browser, but fails when testing with this setup

```
var browser = new Browser(with => 
{
    with.Module<Foobar>();
}

var response = brower.Get("/Foo", with => {with.HttpRequest();});
```

Any clue why the Routebuilder for testing won't pick up this route?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had created the test project using the pre-release version of Nancy.Testing.  This in turn made TinyIOC unhappy when trying to build routes/dependencies.  So, if you see this mysterious message, check that your working code and test code are referencing the same packages.